# fill the JSON file automatically, using a random

Tags: python, json, python-3.6

there is a JSON file that has this kind of view

```
{
"A": 
{
   "B": 0, 
   "C": 1
},
"D": 
{
   "E": 2, 
   "F": 4
}
}
```

I need  that after reading the file by the program, each field of structures "A" and "D" to be given a random value from a certain range to get a new JSON file, for example

```
 {
"A": 
{
   "B": 70, 
   "C": 25
},
"D": 
{
   "E": 15, 
   "F": 3
}
}
```

I wrote a read from the file, but here's how to make each field get a value from a certain range, I do not know

```
import json
from pathlib import Path
path = Path('newtest.json')
data =json.loads(path.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))
data['A']={'B':50,'C':50}
path.write_text(json.dumps(data),
encoding='utf-8')
```

in this piece of code, I set the field values ​​manually, but if there are a lot of fields, I can not set each value manually, how to automate it and wave it with values. value of each field from its range?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what? A dictionary of dictionaries for which you have the key and subkey and you want to change the values of the subkey within a certain range, right? so that {A:{B:70}} can be, assuming keys 1:100, arbitrarily reassigned to {A:{B:42}}, right?

So, assuming you know how to change {A:{B:70}} to {A:{B:35}} in a function, how would you replace 35 with a random number in the range 1:100? You'd look in the standard library for a function to return a random number from a range, right?

Answer (score 0):

Do you means this?

```
import json
import random
from pathlib import Path
path = Path('newtest.json')
data =json.loads(path.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))
for firstKey, firstValue in data.items():
    for key, value in firstValue.items():
        firstValue[key] = random.randrange(0, 100)
    data[firstKey] = firstValue
path.write_text(json.dumps(data),
encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: but how to make so that to each field B, C and so on, values ​​were set from individual ranges? for example for B from the range (0,1), C from the range (0,256) and so on.

Comment: it may be that some fields are filled in not with numbers, but with letters or words, for example, "B": "hello"

Comment: and that's without changing the text fields, how to make an individual random for each field?

Comment: Your  individual random for each field, maybe give a example